# Could a selector on an NSTimer *ever* get executed in the background?

Tags: ios, background, nstimer

Specifically, I'm looking at the case where the backgrounded app receives a location services update (significant location change). What exactly happens on the background in this scenario? Can any user code run, including pending timers?

Comment: I don't believe so, I think only the location manager delegate method will be invoked, but why don't you try it?   It should be pretty simple to test

Comment: So were you able to proceed?

Comment: @bllakjakk At the following link is my main bug, I'm asking this question to try to understand what may be causing it. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/51272/sfcrypto-keychain-data-missing-or-corrupted

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like below using the background Task and Timer:

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        self.locationManager.delegate = self;

        [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
        return YES;
    }

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{

    self.bgTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{


        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:self.bgTask];
        self.bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];


    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60
                                                  target:self
                                                selector:@selector(changeAccuracy)
                                                userInfo:nil
                                                 repeats:YES];
}


- (void) changeAccuracy {
    [self.locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
    [self.locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)lm didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{
    CLLocation *location = [locations lastObject];

    NSLog(@"Location returned: %f, %f Accuracy: %f", location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude, location.horizontalAccuracy);
    [lm setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers];
    [lm setDistanceFilter:99999];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but my question is not how to achieve it with a background task. My question is, will it (firing of the timer) ever occur with location services and a regular timer.

Comment: Definitely yes. Apple allow some specific services to be used while in background. Location is one of them. It can be achieved using background task and timer. It is documented at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html